# Database table designing for sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a two table named customer and Group_Customer. Customer table has NID, Name and Father_Name field where NID is primary key. And Group_Customer has GroupID, Group_Name, and NID field where NID is foregin key of customer table. I want to add a group customer which have 3 records of customer table. When i add Group Customer with the primary key of Customer NID field it could not be one record. Is it possible one record of group customer with two record of customer?

tblCustomer

```
NID     Name                Father_Name
101555      Mr. Debashish       Mr. Deb kumar
101556      Mr. Nibash      Mr. Debashish
101557      Nandika Rani        Mr. Debashish
```

tblGroup_Customer

```
GroupID     Group_Name          NID
1001        Mr. Debashish and Brothers  101555
1001        Mr. Debashish and Brothers  101556
```

The group customer name 'Mr. Debashish and Brothers' which has two customers and there NID is 101555 and 101556. Is it possible one record of group customer with two record of customer?

Comment: What exact do you want ? Do you want that a group can have one or more customers ? Or do you want a customer can have one or more groups ? Or do you want both ?

Comment: @Larnu Thanks for reply. I want a group can have one or more customers.

Comment: I didn't make a comment, Debashish , I editted your post. The comment is by @GuidoG ...

Comment: I think you need to read up about normalization. It seems like you should have only 1 row in tblGroup_Customer. Then in tblCustomer you would need to add a column for GroupID. And make that column have a foreign key constraint. I would also suggest not adding prefixes to your object names but that is more preference than functional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read up on a technique called `normalization` which will make these things more clear to you.

If what you need is that a group can have, 1 or more customers, than you should add a column `GroupID` to your customer table

```
create table tblGroup (
  GroupID int not null, 
  GroupName varchar(100),
  constraint PK_GroupID primary key (GroupID)
)
  
create table tblCustomer (
  CustomerID int not null, 
  Name varchar(100), 
  FatherName varchar(100),
  GroupID int not null,
  constraint PK_CustomerID primary key (CustomerID),
  constraint FK_Customer_Group foreign key (GroupID) references tblGroup (GroupID)
  )
```

Consider [this DBFiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/PClNdIOC) where you can see how to create, populate and query the tables

In this example, every customer must have a group, if that is not required then create the column `GroupID`in `tblCustomer` as nullable, `GroupID int null`
In this case a customer can exist without being a member of a group

Comment: I create another table named order which has field like ID, OrderItem, GroupID. I need to show records between two table's fields Name, FatherName of customer table and OrderItem of order table. In this situation when i inner join between customer table to my order table. Its repeat the Order row 3 times which matches (GroupID) between two table. But i want only show records which matches (GroupID) between two table. How to do it?

Comment: can you open the DBFiddle example in my answer, and add that new table there with some sample data, then I can take a look at it

Comment: Why would you put GroupID in the order table ? Does the group place an order or a customer ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible to have multiple customers of one group.

Reason is that you can have multiple foreign keys in a table, while making sure that the foreign key column should not be set to unique.

Comment: Please tell me details with sample database.